# How can I change the HTML of an element when different options are selected in a separate <select> element?

Tags: javascript, html

So on my website, I'm trying to make it so that when you select a certain Course Name using the `<select>` element, you also change The HTML of the Course Description directly below it so that the Description corresponds with the course. Here's what I've got so far:

```js
< script >
  function myFunctionHTML() {
    document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like coding"
  };

function myFunctionComp() {
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like computers"
};
var H = document.getElementById('Course_HTML').innerHTML;
var C = document.getElementById('Course_Comp').innerHTML;
var Course_Select = document.getElementById('Course_Name').innerHTML;

function myFunctionVar() {
  if Course_Select = H {
    myFunctionHTML();
  }
  if Course_Select = C {
    myFunctionComp();
  }
}; < /script>
```

```html
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Name</label>
<select id="Course_Name" name="Course_Name" onchange="myFunctionVar()" style="width:95%;" required>
  <option value="IntroHTML" id="Course_HTML">Intro to HTML and CSS</option>
  <option value="BuildComputers" id="Course_Comp">Build A Computer</option>
</select>
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Description</label>
<p id="Course_Description">Hi there</p>
```

I'm pretty sure the myFunctionVar() is just wrong, but after researching on other websites and other questions I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Please take some time to format and validate your code first. It has many errors.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, guys! And as I said before, I'm a novice, so I don't know how to properly write and format the code very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need write that much of code to just change `innerHTML` of an element by change in `select` options.

You can refactor your code to be very simple and more readable and even extendable for future `options` on select.

```js
var htmlDesc = "I like coding"; 
var compDesc = "I like computers"; 
//keep more course descriptions here

function changeDescription(e) {
  
  var desc = compDesc;
  
  if(e.value === "IntroHTML")
    desc = htmlDesc; //default HTML description
  //keep more conditions to check for course selected
  
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = desc; //changing innerHTML of description holder
};
```

```html
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Name</label>
<select id="Course_Name" name="Course_Name" onchange="changeDescription(this);" style="width:95%;" required>
  <option value="IntroHTML" id="Course_HTML">Intro to HTML and CSS</option>
  <option value="BuildComputers" id="Course_Comp">Build A Computer</option>
</select>

<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Description</label>
<p id="Course_Description">I like coding</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Remove ";" from functions. Then, you should get the value attribute of option and not innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

First get the value of selected option and then change the description

```
  var e = document.getElementById(selectId);
  var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

```js
function myFunctionHTML() {
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like coding"
}

function myFunctionComp() {
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like computers"
}
var H = document.getElementById('Course_HTML').innerHTML;
var C = document.getElementById('Course_Comp').innerHTML;
var Course_Select = document.getElementById('Course_Name').innerHTML;

function myFunctionVar(selectId) {

  var e = document.getElementById(selectId);
  var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  
  if (option === "IntroHTML") {
    myFunctionHTML();
  }
  if (option === "BuildComputers") {
    myFunctionComp();
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Name</label>
<select id="Course_Name" name="Course_Name" onchange="myFunctionVar('Course_Name')" style="width:95%;" required>
  <option value="IntroHTML" id="Course_HTML">Intro to HTML and CSS</option>
  <option value="BuildComputers" id="Course_Comp">Build A Computer</option>
</select>
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Description</label>
<p id="Course_Description">Hi there</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the error free code of yours try to replace it, with your code and test is works as you expected.
removed `;` from you code
corrected syntax error in `if condition

```
 function myFunctionHTML() {
    document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like coding";
  }

function myFunctionComp() {
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like computers";
}
var H = document.getElementById('Course_HTML').innerHTML;
var C = document.getElementById('Course_Comp').innerHTML;
var Course_Select =  document.getElementById('Course_Name').innerHTML;

function myFunctionVar() {
  if (Course_Select == 'H') {
    myFunctionHTML();
  }
  if (Course_Select == 'C') {
    myFunctionComp();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code

```
    <label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Name</label>
    <select id="Course_Name" name="Course_Name" onchange="myFunctionVar()" style="width:95%;" required>
    <option value="IntroHTML" id="Course_HTML">Intro to HTML and CSS</option>
    <option value="BuildComputers" id="Course_Comp">Build A Computer</option>
    </select>
    <label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Description</label>
    <p id="Course_Description">Hi there</p>
  <script>
            function myFunctionHTML()   {
                document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like coding" 
            }
            function myFunctionComp()   {
                document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like computers" 
            }

            function myFunctionVar()    {
      var H = document.getElementById('Course_HTML').innerHTML
            var C = document.getElementById('Course_Comp').innerHTML


      var e = document.getElementById("Course_Name");
            var Course_Select = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (Course_Select == 'IntroHTML')
        {
         myFunctionHTML()
        }
        else if (Course_Select == 'BuildComputers')
        {
            myFunctionComp()
        }
      }
      </script>
```

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ohd5r1ox/

Answer (score 0):

I have made some Corrections in your code,Please try this..

```js
function myFunctionHTML() {
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like coding";
};

function myFunctionComp() {
  document.getElementById('Course_Description').innerHTML = "I like computers";
};
var H = document.getElementById('Course_HTML').value;
var C = document.getElementById('Course_Comp').value;

function myFunctionVar() {
  var Course_Select = document.getElementById('Course_Name').value;

  if (Course_Select == H) {
    myFunctionHTML();
  }
  if (Course_Select == C) {
    myFunctionComp();
  }
};
```

```html
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Name</label>
<select id="Course_Name" name="Course_Name" onchange="myFunctionVar()" style="width:95%;" required>
  <option value="IntroHTML" id="Course_HTML">Intro to HTML and CSS</option>
  <option value="BuildComputers" id="Course_Comp">Build A Computer</option>
</select>
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black">Course Description</label>
<p id="Course_Description">Hi there</p>
```